# Why can't I use traits with forwarding references in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, perfect-forwarding

I have the following test code.

See godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/fLRM8d for an executable example

```
template <typename T> struct Traits {
    static const bool value = false;
};

struct Zip{};
template <> struct Traits<Zip> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename E>
void Execute(E && e){
    static_assert(Traits<E>::value);
}

int main(){

    auto z = Zip();

    // Fails the static assertion with an lvalue
    Execute(z);

    // Passes the static assertion with an rvalue
    Execute(Zip());
}
```

What is going on here that I can't use my type trait as I expect? What is the correct way to model this problem?

Comment: This question is really important I think, because we have to put remove_reference everywhere now in c++20 with the constraints and concepts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a special rule regarding deduction of forwarding references in the Standard. Given a forwarding reference parameter `T&&`, `T` will be deduced as an *lvalue reference* if the function is called with an *lvalue*.

You need to take this into account in your traits:

```
Traits<std::remove_reference_t<E>>::value
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/z/D_w56W)

---

From the Standard:

http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3

> A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])). If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

Comment: This is the correct answer for what I asked. However I also tried to solve it another way which is to create a specialization for references using enable_if. But it doesn't work. https://godbolt.org/z/NHe25w I can update my question with a followup if you think it's worth it.

Comment: @P.W: added a quote.

Comment: I created a followup question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742648/why-cant-i-add-a-layer-of-abstraction-with-type-lookup-to-strip-references-in-c

Comment: `std::decay_t` seems even better handle `const Zip&` too.

Comment: @Jarod42: true. Probably best to use `remove_cvref` though