# Why can't I add a layer of abstraction with type lookup to strip references in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, perfect-forwarding

This is kind of a followup question to

[Why can't I use traits with forwarding references in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742062/why-cant-i-use-traits-with-forwarding-references-in-c/53742087#53742087)

which has been correctly answered. However I tried my own solution below

https://godbolt.org/z/X7dBz1

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename enable = void> struct Traits {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T> struct Traits<T,std::enable_if<std::is_reference<T>::value>> {
    static const bool value = Traits<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;

};

struct Zip{};
template <> struct Traits<Zip,void> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename E>
void Execute(E && e){
    static_assert(Traits<E>::value);
}

int main(){
    auto z = Zip();
    Execute(z);
}
```

the theory being that if the correct specialisation fails then the next most specialized will be the one that matches based on if `T` is a reference. If this matches then the reference is stripped and we recurse hopefully getting a match. But this does not seem to work. Is there a way to fix this that keep the spirit of my attempt?

Comment: A classical typo, I've been there too. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misusing `std::enable_if`. As written, your `Traits` struct is specialized on `std::enable_if` itself, not its result. You need to access the nested `::type` type alias:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_reference<T>::value>::type
// or
std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference<T>::value>
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/z/eLF0Ho)

Answer (score 3):

N.B. you can also do it without `enable_if` (looks cleaner, IMO):

```
template <typename> struct Traits {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct Traits<T&> : Traits<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct Traits<T&&> : Traits<T> {};
```

Comment: You are right :) https://godbolt.org/z/jbn11v Vittorio still wins the correct answer because it's exactly solving what I asked but I'll be using your solution. Thanks